# Composition of a monotonic and periodic function.

Tags: analysis, functions, periodic-functions, function-and-relation-composition

We have functions in the domain of the real numbers. $f$ is a monotonic function and $h$ is a periodic function. Show that the composition $f\circ h$ is periodic.
I have tried so hard to use the definitions and then come to a conclusion but I cannot solve this. As I understand it, for it to be periodic, there must exist a $T$ (different from $0$) so that this is true:
$$f(h(x) + T)=f(h(x)).$$
What can I do now?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should rather prove $f(h(x+T)) = f(h(x))$ that is obvious since $h(x+T) = h(x)$ (periodicity)

Answer (score 2):

Let $T$ be the period of $h$. Then $f(h(x+T)) = f(h(x))$, and hence $f \circ h$ is periodic with period $T$.

$f(h(x)+T)$ has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Nor do we need $f$ to be monotonic.